# openbsd installation with certain configuration prebuilt

Tags: openbsd

I am looking for options to install a system OpenBSD which has certain configs prewritten. What options can I look for?

1. An install image which when installed, installs a system with a configuration
2. A shell script with root privilege which does the required configuration after a regular install
3. Remote configuration of the target system after a regular install

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: How many machines do you need to pre-configure?  If it is more than a few you want to look at puppet and friends (See http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Puppet_OpenBSD as an example)

Comment: actually, puppet seems to be overkill... The purpose why I want to do this is because I don't have skilled man-power to do the configuration at remote end server and want to automate the process..

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to http://openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#site. This is the official recommendation for to customize the installation.